# How to access raw image from Github?

Tags: html, reactjs, github

I stored my images in Github repo, but when I need to access the raw image

I will get a random token

let a_RandomToken= "AAAAA"

`https://github.com/raw/example?token=${a_RandomToken}`

but the token will be change after a few day

I tried to use personal token to access it

let  a_Personal_Token='BBB'

`https://github.com/raw/example?access_token=${a_Personal_Token}`

but I got "404: Not Found"

I just want to git the raw image url to display the picture on my React/HTML

Comment: I don't think github repositories are meant to be linked to like this. Have you looked at https://pages.github.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is intentional that the tokens used here expire and are specific to a URL.  That's because in the general case, exposing a URL temporarily should not grant permanent access to the resource.  Just because you happen to want a permanent link to a private file doesn't mean that that's a good idea for most people from a security perspective.

It isn't intended for you to use the raw endpoints to host content on your site.  They aren't a CDN or image storage location.  If you want to host this content on your site, include the images as part of your site when you build it, or host them on a CDN somewhere.